# Why Shiva is called Nataraja?

Tags: shiva

Why Shiva is called Nataraja? Is Shiva the king of something?

[image: shiva]

Comment: Related [What is Apasmara?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6883/3500) and [What is the symbolic representation of Swami Natarajar? What is the reason of using him in all classical dances?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10642/3500)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Nat (Sanskrit word) stands for dance
- Raj (Sanskrit word) stands for sovereign or king.

It is believed that Shiva does dance called [Tandava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandava) when it is required to destroy the universe. This dance (Tandava) of Shiva is believed as vigorous dance that is the source of the cycle of creation, preservation and dissolution.

Due to it's significance of controlling the universe by energy of dance (Tandava), Shiva is called supreme lord of dance i.e Natraj (नटराज).

Comment: Yes,  even honey bees and other bees also dance and that vibration tells other bee where the food is. How magical it is!! When they are near honeypot they dance with gravity and when they search foods they dance with the angle of sun light. Magic of shiva....!!!!